getting "Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'." could it be issues with google?
I'm getting error

Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.

can it be due to google api issues stated in here > ?
https://status.play.google.com/
is there a way to go around it ?
I have internet permission in the app and I'm using
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.5.0'
    implementation('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }

full error:
2024-10-28 18:39:19.725 17144-: Failed to get service from broker. 
    java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3182)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3166)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3149)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3091)
        at anag.a(:com.google.android.gms@244232029@24.42.32 (190400-688217902):36)
        at amyn.z(:com.google.android.gms@244232029@24.42.32 (190400-688217902):143)
        at amfs.run(:com.google.android.gms@244232029@24.42.32 (190400-688217902):54)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at bsep.mx(:com.google.android.gms@244232029@24.42.32 (190400-688217902):1)
        at bsep.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@244232029@24.42.32 (190400-688217902):5)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:68)
2024-10-28 18:39:19.917 26364-26506/? E/A: (REDACTED) Trace %s timed out after %d ms. Complete trace: %s
    com.google.apps.tiktok.tracing.fo: 
        at tk_trace.GIL:ClearcutTransmitter(Started After:1)
        at tk_trace.GIL:NVLGraftHandler(Started After:1)
        at tk_trace.GIL:FlushHostBatch(Started After:1)
        at tk_trace.handleBroadcast(Started After:0)
        at tk_trace.Broadcast to com.google.android.libraries.assistant.contexttrigger.impl.ContextTriggerBroadcastReceiver_Receiver TIME TRIGGER ALLOW IDLE ACTION(Started After:0)
2024-10-28 18:39:37.367 968-1023/? E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 123 ms


You might be breaking a dependency with the exclude and then wonder why it's broken? Trying to optimize while nothing works is ordinary not the order of tasks which leads to results. And this is also the problem with this question, you're not telling why you even do that.

I am getting the exact same exception. I also could not find much info online. But I don't think it causes any wrong behavior, soo I decided to leave it in and don't worry about it for now. Also I have crashlytics setup & they aren't picking it up, so it might just be a simulator/development issue
